# Pandas unexpectedly casts type in heterogeneous dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

if I define a dataframe like this

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
str1= ["woz", "baz", "fop", "jok"]
arr=np.array([2,3,4])
data = {"Goz":str1, "Jok": np.hstack((np.array([5,"fava"]), np.array ([1,2]) ) ) }
df = pd.DataFrame(data)



Goz Jok
0   woz 5
1   baz fava
2   fop 1
3   jok 2
```

I am puzzled by the fact those nice floats in the second column, coming from a numpy array, are cast to string

```
type(df.loc[3]["Jok"])
out:: str
```

Further, if I try to manually cast back to float64 for a subset of the dataframe, say

```
df.iloc[2:,1].astype("float64", copy=False)
```

the type of the does not change. Besides I understand the`copy=False` option, comes with extreme danger.

If on the other hand I define the dataframe using this

```
data = {"Goz":str1, "Jok": np.array ([1,2,3,4])  }
```

having hence the whole column to contain float64 uniformly, all seems to work.
Can somebody please clarify what is going on here?  How to handle type-heterogenous columns? Thanks a lot

Comment: Pandas doesn't support "heterogeneous" dtypes. You should have 1 dtype per column only. Numbers can be cast to string but strings cannot be cast to number types that is the explanation for "I am puzzled by the fact those nice floats in the second column, coming from a NumPy array, are cast to string".

Comment: Pandas is not doing this. `np.hstack` is. If you inspect the result of this statement you will find it is strings: `x = np.hstack((np.array([5,"fava"]), np.array ([1,2])))` If you create a list with strings and numbers you can have mixed types (or technically, a type of object for the column, with numbers and string in it): `data = {"Goz":str1, "Jok": [5,"fava",1,2] }`

Comment: A pandas column, a Series, will be object dtype if it contains strings. That can also have floats.  But a `np.array[-([1,'a'])` will have a string dtype.  Mixing strings and numbers is done differently in numpy and pandas.

Comment: thanks to you all, I missed this point